# highlighting the row a dynamically created table

Tags: javascript

i have json data like this:

```
     var myContacts = [{
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RancorService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RancorService/JP",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (36)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RancorService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RancorService/JP",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC (leastconns,ROUNDROBINSHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN)",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (56)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "NC : >1 VIP's MISSING TIER-1 TAG",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "NO",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (ssl-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "NC : SHOULD BE DISABLED (YES)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/EU",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (16)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/JP",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  }
];
```

i have a function that creates a dynamic table:

```
    function generateDynamicTable(myContacts) {
      var noOfContacts = myContacts.length;

      if (noOfContacts > 0) {


        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.style.width = '100%';
        table.setAttribute('border', '1');
        table.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
        table.setAttribute('id','example');
        table.setAttribute('class', 'stripe row-border order-column');
        table.setAttribute('cellpadding', '5');



        var col = []; // define an empty array
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfContacts; i++) {
          for (var key in myContacts[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              col.push(key);
            }
          }
        }

        // CREATE TABLE HEAD .
        var tHead = document.createElement("thead");


        // CREATE ROW FOR TABLE HEAD .
        var hRow = document.createElement("tr");

        // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
          var th = document.createElement("th");
          th.innerHTML = col[i];
          hRow.appendChild(th);
        }
        tHead.appendChild(hRow);
        table.appendChild(tHead);

        // CREATE TABLE BODY .
        var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfContacts; i++) {

          var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); // CREATE ROW FOR EACH RECORD


          for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            var tempVal = (myContacts[i][col[j]] != null) ? myContacts[i][col[j]].toString() : "";
            td.innerHTML = tempVal;
            if (tempVal.startsWith("Consistent")||tempVal.startsWith("MAX-CONNS")) {
              td.innerHTML = 'Consistent';
            }
            if (tempVal.startsWith("NC")) {
              td.innerHTML = '';
              var a = document.createElement('a');
              var linkText = document.createTextNode("Non Consistent");
              a.appendChild(linkText);
              a.title = "Check details";
              a.href = "http://example.com";
              td.appendChild( a );
            }

            bRow.appendChild(td);

            //codes for highlighting row inserted here


          }
          tBody.appendChild(bRow)

        }
        table.appendChild(tBody);
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("demo");
        divContainer.innerHTML ="";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
   }
```

I want to hightlight the row in which i hover the mouse pointer and i inserted the following code for that after this line bRow.appendChild(td);

```
            bRow.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor="#FDFF47";
            });
            bRow.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor="white";
            });
```

but this didnot work, instead only single cell is getting highlighted.
but i want entire row to get highlight, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bRoW -> letter 'W' should be small letter.

```
    //codes for highlighting row inserted here
    bRow.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor="#FDFF47";
    });
    bRow.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor="white";
    });
```

To highlight entire row, place below script  after **divContainer.appendChild(table);**

```
var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

        for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i += 1) {
            tableRows[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
                //event.target.style.backgroundColor="#FDFF47";
                this.style.background = "#FDFF47";
            });
            tableRows[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {
                //event.target.style.backgroundColor="white";
                this.style.background = "white";
            });
        }
```

Still, you can use CSS class to achieve this target. Add below line after table row creation **var bRow = document.createElement("tr");**

```
  bRow.className = "tb-row";
```

Create a simple CSS style in the same page.

```
<style>
.tb-row:hover{
    background: #FDFF47;
}
</style>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: yeah corrected them, but only single cell is getting highlighted. I want the entire row to get highlighted.

Comment: @Himanshu I have modified answer to highlight entire row. You can give a try.